# Undefined control sequence \coloneqq

Tags: symbols, errors, lyx

I'm trying to export a PDF of a LyX document (it has never caused a problem before). Below I have posted pictures of the error message along with the equation LyX highlighted for me. I don't know what `\hbox` is, and I didn't use that in my code. Can someone please help me edit the equation so that I can export a PDF?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This `\hbox` thing is just an example for a typo, has nothing to do with your text!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The command `\coloneqq` is unknown, you need to load a package for this, such as `mathtools`, `txfonts` or `pxfonts`.

Add to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

[LyX 2.1](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX21#commands) will have direct `mathtools` support.

Comment: Thank you. Where would I type this "\usepackage{mathtools}"?

Comment: The document preamble can be edited via the LyX menu: Document/ Settings.

Comment: I'm using Lyx 2.2.2 and have to force the use of mathtools from Document / Settings, the auto detect setting seems broken.